# I\O race condition when using TraceListener

Tags: c#, trace

I'm using a TraceListener of Type TextWriterTraceListener.
I'm using WriteLine on this Listener from several threads.
Though Is​Thread​Safe == false and  UseGlobalLock == True I keep getting I\O Race condition issue.From what I have read this is not the expected results since Trace should Lock with the global lock.

If I use CriticalSection at each call to WriteLine I don't get this error.

One thread is writing at 100 Hz and another thread is writing at 10 Hz.

I appreciate some advice .